# youtube direct lite video unable to play

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have configured and setup the youtube direct lite and deployed the app in the google app engine.I am able to submit videos and these videos are approved and a approval mail is successfully send.But when I am trying to embed the playlist code of the uploaded video,

```
<object width="480" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/p/PLwNZwNRcLsUoRtvyzHc3dYz1uLV_z9R2M?   fs=1"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/p/PLwNZwNRcLsUoRtvyzHc3dYz1uLV_z9R2M?fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

I am getting a white screen with no video shown.The video link that is generated also says the link is broken.But that is automatically generated link and it cant be broken.pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you describe, I believe you're using [YouTube Direct](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/), not [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/). I'd recommend using the newer, more maintained YouTube Direct Lite at this point.

In any case, I just updated the code that gives out playlist embeds in YouTube Direct's admin interface to use the new iframe playlist player syntax, which should work better:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/source/detail?r=633

Try updating your YouTube Direct installation to pick up that new code, and regenerate your playlist embed code from the admin interface.